# Trigger function does not update the first row of the table

Tags: postgresql, triggers, gis

I am working in PostgreSQL 9.5 where I have these two tables:

Table **incident**:

```
  oid integer 
  description integer,
  geom geometry(Point,4326),
```

And table **grid**:

```
  oid integer,
  number integer,
  geom geometry(Polygon,4326)
```

Everytime a point is added to table **incident** I want the field *description* to be filled with the grid number that the point is intersecting. To achieve this I created this trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_ortofoto_incidentes()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
   BEGIN      
       SELECT g.number INTO NEW.description 
       FROM incident AS i, grid AS g 
       WHERE st_intersects(new.geom, g.geom) ; -- 
RETURN NEW;
   END;
$BODY$
   LANGUAGE 'plpgsq;
```

And added it to the table **incident**:

```
CREATE TRIGGER get_ortofoto_incidentes
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON incidentestest  
  FOR each row
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE get_ortofoto_incidentes();
```

The problem is that when the trigger function is called the attribute *description* remains null for the first row, but after the trigger works as expected. This is what I am getting:

```
oid | description
 1  |  null
 2  | 236541
 3  | 695489
 4  | 325687
... |  ....
```

Any idea why the trigger is not updating for the first row of the table?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that it is a coincidence that this happens only for the first inserted row. It is completely ok for `description` to be set to `NULL` if the first matching row in `grid` has `NULL` in `number`.

I also want to warn you that the query in your trigger function builds a Cartesian product between the matching rows from `grid` and the table `incident`, since there is no `WHERE` condition restricting the latter. Remove the `incident AS i` from the query.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz, good point on the `incident AS i`. I removed it and now the trigger works as expected even for the first row. Though I understand your point I am not sure why it was causing my problem, but the fact is, it works!